# Please confirm what Cooper says

Tags: listening

I know as a site policy dictation is not welcomed, but it is really hard for me to catch what cooper says [at this scene,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjkVgc6gIqk), can someone please help me? 0.15~0.27

---

With the help of @Colin Fine, I corrected. Has this become perfect?

> 「Every day, once a day, give you some presents. Don't plan it, don't wait it, just let it happen. **It could be a new shirt at men's store, a cat nap in your office chair,** or just 2 cups of good hot mug coffee!」

Thank you in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new shirt at the men's store, a cat-nap in your office chair

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate/check the verbs or something before "a new shirt" or "a cat nap", will you?

Comment: "It could be", @Kentaro